# Understading the Recall function in R

Tags: r, recursion

I have a data frame like this:

```
> Df
   X1     X2     X3
1  event1 event2 event5
2  event1 event2 event5
3  event1 event2 event6
4  event1 event2 event6
5  event1 event3 event7
6  event1 event3 event7
7  event1 event3 event7
8  event1 event4 event7
9  event1 event4 event7
10 event1 event4 event7
```

(Real data frame contains over 20 cols and thousands of rows).

My aim here is to add a label in column3, so that I know which event in Column2 the events in Column3 are associated with. "Associated" here means, for row and column i+1 and j+1, what is the event at row and column i and j. This is, the Final data.frame here should look like:

```
> final.Df
   X1     X2     X3
1  event1 event2 event5.n1
2  event1 event2 event5.n1
3  event1 event2 event6.n1
4  event1 event2 event6.n1
5  event1 event3 event7.n2
6  event1 event3 event7.n2
7  event1 event3 event7.n2
8  event1 event4 event7.n3
9  event1 event4 event7.n3
10 event1 event4 event7.n3
```

(note that n1, n2, or n3 are arbitrary, can be anything as long as are the same in Col3 if the event in Col2 is identical). At the moment I have accomplished it using a series of `for` and `if` loops. However, I would like to understand the `Recall` function in R and code it in a much more compact way.

To that aim I wrote this function:

```
rename.cols <- function(nod = 1, j = 3, init =1) {
    ##generating labels to add
    node.name <- paste(".n", nod, sep = "") 
    ##adding label to 1st row in each block 
    Df[init,j] <- paste(Df[init,j],node.name, sep="") 
    ##adding labels in col j while elements in col j-1 are identical
    while (init+1 <= nrow(Df) & Df[init+1,j-1] == Df[init,j-1]){
        Df[init+1,j] = paste(Df[init+1,j],node.name, sep="")
        init = init + 1
    }
    ##while the end of the Df is not reached, Recall the function again
    ##using updated parameters
    if (init+1 < nrow(Df)) Recall(nod = nod+1, j = 3, init = init+1)
    else print("end")
    return(Df)
}
```

where `nod` is used to create the labels to add to the values in col `j` and `init` is just the initial value from which the function starts adding labels to col `j`.

At the moment, this function returns a data frame where only the first 4 rows in Column 3 (i.e. only those corresponding to `event2` in Column2) have been updated. The rest remain the same.

The function returns no error, and I positively know that the `Recall` function occurs. Therefore, I am assuming that the function does not work as expected due to the (bad) use of `return` or `recall` (or surely both). I posted a question regarding to recursive programming in R a few months ago. But still I am not managing to use `Recall` properly.

Therefore, the question is: How I should use `Recall` in this context so that the output is the desired data frame shown above.

Thank you.

Comment: You are not using the return value of `Recall`.  Values computed within the function are in their own environment, and don't propagate to callers, even if the caller is the same function.  Using `DF <- Recall(...)` may fix this, but a loop would be much clearer.  Recursion isn't always the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the second and further invocations of the function (through `Recall`), you are throwing away the result.  The assignment to `DF` within each function call is assigning to a copy of the data frame.  It works with a loop because the same object is being modified each time.

There are two bad ways to fix this code.

1. Change to global assignment in `DF`:

   `Df[init,j] <<- paste(Df[init,j],node.name, sep="")
   ...
   Df[init+1,j] <<- paste(Df[init+1,j],node.name, sep="")`
2. Capture the output of `Recall` and reassign to `DF`:

   `if (init+1 < nrow(Df)) DF <- Recall(nod = nod+1, j = 3, init = init+1)`

The first is bad because global assignment is not functional, and in general leads to hard-to-find errors.  The second is creating a new copy of DF for each iteration.

A loop is the appropriate structure for this task.  Recursion is only emulating a loop.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, loop will be then. I guess since I am not that familiar with recursion I "force" myself to use it. Thanks again.

Comment: In any case, in case is of any use, your option 2 does not provide the desired result (i.e. I have left everything as it is and modified the line you mention: `if (init+1 < nrow(Df)) DF <- Recall(nod = nod+1, j = 3, init = init+1)`). It returns a data frame with the last 3 rows in Col3 updated (those corresponding to event4 in col2) but the rest of the data frame remains unchanged. Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a straightforward solution using dplyr and stringr

```
library(tidyverse)
x1<-rep("e1",10)
x2<-c(rep("e2",4),rep("e3",3),rep("e4",3))
x3<-c(rep("e5",2),rep("e6",2),rep("e7",6))
df<-as.tibble(cbind(x1,x2,x3))

df%>%
group_by(x2)%>%
mutate(x3=str_c(x3,x2,sep="."))
```